# How set different state directory for multiple instances of the same Kafka Streams application on a single machine

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

From version 2.6.0, KafkaStreams with states locks the **state.dir** directory and as the documentation says

> The state directory. Kafka Streams persists local states under the state directory. Each application has a subdirectory on its hosting machine that is located under the state directory. The name of the subdirectory is the application ID. The state stores associated with the application are created under this subdirectory. **When running multiple instances of the same application on a single machine, this path must be unique for each such instance.**

In the scenario of running multiple instances of the same application on a single machine,
The path cannot be a random path like **/state/dir/{uuid}** because this solution bypass the [KAFKA-10716](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10716) issue.

My solution is to have a directory like **/state/dir** with ordinal subdirectories, e.g., 0,1,2... and each instance on startup checks this subdirectories from 0 and finds the first subdirectory that is not locked and use that directory for **state.dir**. As a result, the process id is read from metafile and the previous tasks will be assign to new process correctly.

Is this a correct solution?

What is the best practice to set a different path for each instance on a single machine?

Comment: One instance can use multiple `num.stream.threads` for concurrency. Why run multiple JVM instances?

Comment: @OneCricketeer One instance brings single point of failure for any reason if an app crashes. Besides that in scenarios that KafkaStreams has 30 tasks (one per thread), it is better to use multi processing instead of multi thread for context switch and cpu usage reasons.

Comment: If the JVM crashes, there's probably a good reason it does so (e.g OOM, NPE). Otherwise, exception handlers can be added to the stream processors. You can always use a process scheduler to restart failed processes, so it's not truly a SPoF

Comment: You are right but still three are benefits in multi processing programming when tasks are cpu intensive e.g., better usage of multiple cpu cores, lower heap size and gc time, lower context switch time, thread waiting time. Also, if for any unknown reason a task goes to shutdown state (the thread unhandled exceptions) only a small subset of tasks will be restarted. As the Kafka document says about **state.dir** they predicted it by setting a unique directory for each instance and we cannot extend the multi threading programming for all scales, it is only good for small topic partitions.

Comment: In any case, back to the question. The documentation doesn't prescribe any solution other than being unique. Creating the ordinal directories at runtime doesn't really make sense to me because you would then need to track/check the locks, like you say. Overall, you do need some process supervision to make sure each instance restarts with its correct state directory, which would be done outside the Kafka api. Otherwise, you'd simply set a hard-coded directory, unique in each instance, maybe using supervisord to template-in the process number

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i also came with a solution that is similar to yours:

I've created a service registry. Each kafka streams instance will request an instance-id when its starting up. The service registry wil then give an integer back beginning from 0. If a second instance comes up, this will get id 1. The instance-id is used to set the **group.instance.id** and the **state.dir** configs.

To make it more reliable, each instance will periodically send a heartbeat request to the service-registry. This is needed to make an instance-id available again in case an instance goes down. It will also unregister itself in a shutdown hook to make its id available again. So if instance-0 restarts, it will then get id 0 again, because 0 is the next lowest available number.

With this solution you dont need to read directories and lock-files.

PS: why dont you just increase the **num.stream.threads**. As you descbribe yourself, you are running it on the same machine (scaling vertically ). With the solution i provided, you can scale horizontally and point the state.dir to the same directory.